# JacORB comiling error on _stub, can't find class

Tags: java, jacorb

i'm trying to get a JacORB example working but i get these errors while compiling the client...

```
_MessageStub.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
if ( _so instanceof org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt)
                                          ^
symbol:   class ServantObjectExt
  location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
_MessageStub.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
                    ((org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt)_so).normalCompletion();
                                            ^
  symbol:   class ServantObjectExt
  location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
_MessageStub.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
                if ( _so instanceof org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt) 
                                                          ^
  symbol:   class ServantObjectExt
  location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
_MessageStub.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
                    ((org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt)_so).exceptionalCompletion(re);
                                            ^
  symbol:   class ServantObjectExt
  location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
_MessageStub.java:93: error: cannot find symbol
                if ( _so instanceof org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt) 
                                                          ^
  symbol:   class ServantObjectExt
  location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
_MessageStub.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
                    ((org.omg.CORBA.portable.ServantObjectExt)_so).exceptionalCompletion(err);
                                            ^
  symbol:   class ServantObjectExt
  location: package org.omg.CORBA.portable
6 errors
```

Seems i miss some JacORB jar files but i have already put all jars in the CLASSPATH.
Someone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please note the official JacORB mailing lists are here : http://www.jacorb.org/contact.html

Please can you elaborate your version, how you are compiling, what you are compiling etc.